# Including a file with the Site Directory - Making Navigation always include connect.php no matter what sub-directory

Tags: php

I've been working on a small site, to work on my PHP Skills. I've got the navigation inside of a sub-folder called Templates. Now basically, the navigation is going to be included on every page, and along with it connect.php. Now the problem is, if it goes into another sub-folder then it isn't going to be able to find the connect.php file. I've got the APP Directory setup, and that is working on the Stylesheet and all.

However I'm not sure how I would do the include, I got the idea/code for the link href from StackOverflow on another question and on that it said that `include (APP_DIR .'connect.php')` however that doesn't seem to work for me, it brings up an error "Warning: include(APP_ROOT/connect.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ytsite\templates\navigation.php on line 2
"

Any help on how to correctly include a file so no matter where it is, it includes the connect would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: have you defined APP_DIR? ..  See 'define' ..  http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: If a constant ist not defined PHP treats it like a string. Also you've stated you want `APP_DIR` but the error message states `APP_ROOT`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I entered it wrong. I have it as APP_ROOT. Also yes, I have defined it @Daniel
`define('APP_ROOT', 'http://localhost/ytsite');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constant should be a directory path, not a url. Try this with your constant definition..

```
define('APP_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ytsite' );

echo APP_ROOT; //to test
```

Not tested. Beware you don't get double slashes and make sure the path goes to the correct directory.
Also make sure you add a slash when you include 'connect.php'. Include it in the constant definition, or add it to your include line.

```
include (APP_ROOT .'/connect.php');
```

**edit**

So include your connect file like this:

Make a master file to include into your pages and add these lines.

```
<?php
    define('APP_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ytsite' );
    include (APP_ROOT .'/connect.php');
?>
```

Every time you launch a new page, the constant needs to be recreated.

Comment: I altered my includes and all to the same as your ones. I echoed the APP_ROOT on the connect.php and then went to ytsite/connect.php and it displayed correctly. However I still get the same issues on my index.php, it has the following errors. 

Notice: Use of undefined constant APP_ROOT - assumed 'APP_ROOT' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ytsite\templates\navigation.php on line 2

Warning: include(APP_ROOT/connect.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in - "Also another one  for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') " I can't fit full error due to character limit.

Comment: PHP does not know your constant. You need to include your constant definition in every file. You could place it above the include ... See added code in answer.